# ASP.NET & JavaScript: Get tree view checked item value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

How to obtain value of selected node of asp.net treeview from javascript?

I have tree:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="dtDivisions" runat="server" onclick="OnDivisionChecked(event);" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="true">
</asp:TreeView>
```

I fill it using next method:

```
private static void BindTreeViewNode(TreeView control, TreeNode parentNode)
{
  int parentId = parentNode == null ? -1 : Convert.ToInt32(parentNode.Value);
  var list = DictionariesDAO.GetListByParentId(DictionaryType.Divisions, parentId);

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(item.Name, item.Id.ToString())
                                {
                                    ImageUrl = item.HasChilds ? "js/dtree/img/folder.gif" : "js/dtree/img/page.gif",
                                    NavigateUrl = item.Id.ToString(),
                                    SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None
                                };

    if (parentNode == null)
    {
      node.ImageUrl = "js/dtree/img/base.gif";
      control.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
    else
    {
      parentNode.ChildNodes.Add(node);
    }

    if (item.HasChilds)
    {
      BindTreeViewNode(control, node);
    }
  }
}
```

I need in **OnDivisionChecked** javascript method obtain value of selected node.
I try to put it in **NavigationUrl** property of TreeView but without success.

Ex:

```
var snode = document.getElementById(TreeNode.id.replace('CheckBox', '').replace('dtDivisionsn', 'dtDivisionst'));
document.getElementById('ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_hidDivisionsId').value = snode.href;
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, but maybe doesn't fit with your case. but I like to share this with you. the idea is very simple, I set `Tooltip` of `Treeview node` with the `Value` and use that in my `js` code.

```
var node = new TreeNode
{
    Text = "SOME_TEXT",
    Value = "VALUE",
    ToolTip = "VALUE"
};
```

Then is js:

```
$('.treeview input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('title'); // this will get you the VALUE
});
```

Answer (score 1):

hopefully the link below can solve ur problem : http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/ASPNET-TreeView-and-Checkboxes.aspx